# Google Maps API - Create a color coded map by neighborhood

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, heatmap

I need to show neighborhood data on a map.
Each neighborhoods color would be based on the value it has.
In google maps the neighborhoods are highlighted by google when I search for them.
I do not see a way to create custom colors for them through the API.
To clarify I want to show a bunch of adjacent neighborhoods in different colors, not change the color of all neighborhoods.

More Info: Thanks Duncan, Google Maps has neighborhood outlines, eg typing menisa, edmonton into Google Maps highlights that neighborhood. Would that be geocoding via neighborhood?

This link is an example of what I am looking for.
http://www.bizjournals.com/boston/real_estate/2013/07/boston-liquor-licenses-database.html

Do I need to use google places to query for the google.maps.places.PlaceGeometry.viewport? And then use heatmaps to specify a weightedvalue?

From reading the documentation it looks to me like Google Maps API does not support this. If so could someone confirm that.

Comment: What does your code look like?  How do you define neighbourhoods?  Are you using polygons, or relying on geocoded address data, or...?  Maybe attach or link to an illustration of what you're wanting this to look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the information to get you started here: [Google Fusion Tables](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/1032332)